# Dynamic State Access vs Static State Access vs Statelessness

Tags: eth-2.0, upgrading, terminology

I have been reading up on ethereum and the changes that come from going from 1.0 to 2.0, but was confused about the terminology of the different "state" types. Would someone mind explaining the differences between dynamic state access, static state access, and statelessness as it relates to ethereum?
Thank You!